# How to create installer for solaris

Tags: unix, installation, solaris, packaging

I have already createdrpm file for my application. It works fine for Fedora linux. also the same worked fine for linux mint. But Solaris does not support rpm. So how to create installer package for solaris OS. I have solaris 10 linux as OS.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solaris OS packaging format (pkgadd) is described in this [Sun Solaris document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/817-0406/).

There is also an open source project called [OpenPKG](http://www.openpkg.org/) that can be used on most Unix/Linux variants. I have not used it myself though.

[Here](http://linuxshellaccount.blogspot.com/2008/03/converting-linux-rpms-into-solaris-pkg.html) is an interesting post about converting RPMs to Solaris Pkg.

Answer (score 0):

Solaris packaging is the way to go. It's a little odd when you first look at it, but it's actually not too difficult once you get your head around it.